# Where can I find canopy reflectance data for crops (soybean in particular) for different dates across the growing season

Tags: remote-sensing, agriculture

I have been trying to find literature values for reflectance of soybean for different dates along the growing season (I am specifically interested in 30, 60 and ~120 days after planting - so the V3/V4 stage, R3/R4 stage and R8 stage) but all the spectral response graphs (there's only graphs - I haven't seen a table) that show up in my literature search have "Average Spectral Response" and no date indicated. There is a [1984 dataset](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19860003273) on the NASA website which has measurement dates mentioned - but no mention of planting date, and the reflectance data doesn't mention the measurement dates either.

Is there a paper or some other resource where I could find such data? I should add that this is for remote-sensing work, hence why I want data for different dates - I want the presence of soil to be accounted for in the reflectances reported.

Comment: Assuming you already looked up publications citing the NASA report, I speculate NIH's pubmed database was not included in the literature search.  Maybe the array of keywords needs further adjustment, a search by `reflectance of soybean growth` (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=reflectance+of+soybean+growth) yields for example entries like https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3784907/, and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5095887/ pointing to the updates on https://www.nass.usda.gov/Research_and_Science/Cropland/metadata/meta.php - what if they know a source?

Comment: You don't say what location you are interested in. It will of course depend on how factors like weather affect the growth stages. But this is more of an agronomy than an earth-science question. There has been quite a bit of research in that literature. Of course, knowing planting date is important and you won't necessarily get that from the remotely sensed data.